# Magento Sales Rules Staging Module Disable Issue

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4, magento2.4.2

I want to disable the Magento Banner module but the module is depend on the below module

i try to disale all the module one by one using command line but when i disable the module sales rule staging command and then run the setup upgrade command then i face a issue with the below error :

while disable and then upgrade then shows the error : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0-1-0-220' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: ALTER TABLE `salesrule_product_attribute` ADD COLUMN `rule_i d` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL   COMMENT "Rule ID", DROP COLUMN `row_id`, DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD CONSTRAINT  PRIMARY KEY (`rule_id`,`website_id`,`customer_group_id`,`attribute_id`
), ADD CONSTRAINT `SALESRULE_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_RULE_ID_SALESRULE_RULE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`rule_id`) REFERENCES `salesrule` (`rule_id`)  ON DELETE CASCADE

so can any one help me out to how to relsolve this ?

i am using magento enterprice colud project version 2.4.2-p1

[image]